# Time consistency issue with ScheduledExecutorService in Java

Tags: java, scheduledexecutorservice

I am trying to invoke a runnable task every 15 minutes using ScheduledExecutorService. The tasks are supposed to run every hour at the following times:
2nd Minute 10th Second
17th Minute 10th Second
32nd Minute 10th Second
47th Minute 10th Second.

I calculate the initial delay for the first execution of the task using the Calendar instance and then use the delay with scheduleAtFixedRate() to execute the task every 15 minutes. This works fine for the first few days but after a few days I can observe some time shift in the execution of the tasks. For example the task that was supposed to start at 12:02:10 gets invoked at 12:03:45 instead. Where am I going wrong with this?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {    
  final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors
                .newScheduledThreadPool(15);
  Date aDate = new Date();
  Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
  cal.setTime(aDate);
  int currentHour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
  int currentMins = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
  int currentSecs = cal.get(Calendar.SECOND);
  int unitInSecs;      
  int delayFor15MinTasksInSecs;
  unitInSecs = currentMins * 60 + currentSecs;
  delayFor15MinTasksInSecs = unitInSecs < (3 * 60 - 50 ) ? (3 * 60 - 50 ) - unitInSecs : unitInSecs < (18 * 60 - 50 ) ? (18 * 60 - 50 ) - unitInSecs : unitInSecs < (33 * 60 - 50 ) ? (33 * 60 - 50 ) - unitInSecs : unitInSecs < (48 * 60 - 50 )? (48 * 60 - 50 ) - unitInSecs : (63 *60 - 50 ) - unitInSecs;
  scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new RTPAcquiringTask(10), delayFor15MinTasksInSecs, 15*60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This API isn't perfect in time-keeping.

From the Javadoc of [`ScheduledExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html):

> Beware however that expiration of a relative delay need not coincide with the current Date at which the task is enabled due to network time synchronization protocols, clock drift, or other factors.

Comment: Is there another way to achieve this?

Comment: Lots to consider when designing a realtime system. Air traffic control is a good model to emulate. Here is some reading that might be helpful: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/nilsen-realtime-pt2-2264409.html

Answer (score 1):

## Not Real-Time

As the [correct Answer by Riaz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34803230/642706) and its comments say, conventional Java implementations such as [Oracle’s](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) or the [OpenJDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJDK) project are not [real-time systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_computing). So they do not keep time perfectly. Classes such as `ScheduledExecutorService` are not intended to keep time perfectly. If need be, look into the attempts at making a [real-time Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_time_Java).

## Workaround

I have not tried this workaround to minimize the drift; just an idea.

As a workaround you may be able to have an extra background thread whose job is to occasionally terminate your current `ScheduledExecutorService` work, and start a fresh one with re-calculated delay number. You say the drift becomes apparent after a few days, so perhaps have this terminate-and-reschedule chore run once daily.

You can track and terminate that `ScheduledExecutorService` work by capturing the [`ScheduledFuture`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledFuture.html) object being returned by your call to `scheduleAtFixedRate`. Currently your call ignores and loses that returned object. Keep track of it, make it available to the background thread I suggest. Call [`cancel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#cancel-boolean-) to terminate.